# what is the difference between the 2 different for-loop(python) :

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

-i want to know the difference between the two different for-loop in case of more than one key. because i got 2 difference result

-second question, can we lop for inside append-fucntion( first method). example : append( for k in ['x']  : )

- third question :can we iterate 2 key at same time ?

example:   :  **for key1, key2 in ['key1','key2','key3',....']**

-I have already tried  the first for-loop inside append-fucntion i got error . But the second method works with no error

```
# first method
b={}

for k in ['x']:

    b.append({k: dic[k]})

#and second method

b.append({k: dic[k] for k in ['x'] })
```

Comment: With only a single key, I'd expect no difference at all. With n keys the first gives a list of n dictionaries with one key-value our each, the second gives a list of one dictionary with (up to) n key-value pairs.

Comment: you are right ,  can we get  one dictionary with n key-value other than the second for-loop method

Comment: Why do you need a different way to do it?

Comment: i want just to learn if exists, thanks for you explanation and your response

Answer (score 0):

Your first loop could be:

```py
b.extend([{k:dic[k]} for k in ['x']])
```

The second is another thing as you mentioned. And I'm not sure to understand your third question. What do you mean by *same time* ?

Comment: thanks for your answer, i means if we can iterate with 2 keys in for loop. for ex. :  **for key1, key2 in ['key1','key2','key3',....']**

Comment: syntax for k1, k2 in iterable means objects in iterable are 2-uple so
for k1, k2 in ['key1', 'key2' etc.] will produce a syntax error